# Manage nuget locally in project.json .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

I don't want to rely on nuget service for downloading dependency. I want to download and use nuget packages locally in my .Net Core app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Approach is the same as was before: open your [NuGet.config](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file) file and add your local feed (path to local folder with pacakages. See [Hosting your own Nuget feed](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) doc):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json" />
    ...
    <add key="LocalFeed" value="<path to your local folder>" />
</packageSources>
```

You can modify default NuGet.config file

> The default location for NuGet's configuration file is %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config (DOS) or $ENV:APPDATA\NuGet\NuGet.Config (PowerShell).

or create your own file in root folder of your solution.