# How to install nuget package as offline in .Net Core projects?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nuget-package

On .Net core web applications when I want to manage my NuGet Packages or add a reference to my project's references, I do right click on references and select "Manage NuGet Package" and now I can add package(s) and if I select install, visual studio downloads selected package and install it on my project.It works fine.

But I want to know how can I use that downloaded NuGet package again on another project?

Should I use package manager and download it again or I can use downloaded files as offline installation?

I have installed packages files on this path on my computer:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\.nuget\packages
```

Comment: You should download and install it again. It will help you to keep always the newest version in all project and easy way to update it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manage nuget locally in project.json .Net Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759865/manage-nuget-locally-in-project-json-net-core)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400069/dotnet-add-package-with-local-package-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and I couldn't find any existing solution, so I had to create [NuSave](https://github.com/anass-b/NuSave).

You give it the name of the package, it will download it with all its dependencies into a local directory of your choice.

Then you can follow [this](http://blog.ittoby.com/2014/07/setup-your-own-chocoloateynuget.html) or [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx) to see how you can setup [NuGet.Server](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Server), a lightweight server that will serve the NuGet packages that you downloaded using [NuSave](https://github.com/anass-b/NuSave). You will then have a localhost URL that you can add to your Visual Studio NuGet sources for offline access.