# VSCode local nuget repository \ source

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, nuget

I'm working on a new nuget package, which I set to be automatically deployed to a certain location on my machine.

However, how do I reference that local nuget package in my demo project using `Package Reference` in my `csproj`?

I mean, how do I add a local nuget repository source in Visual Studio Code?

... or I should always use: `dotnet add package PackageName -Source private-repo-source` with some pre-build task.

Comment: Is that answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400069/add-a-package-with-a-local-package-file-in-dotnet ?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!