# how to add local nuget package in the project file(.csproj)

Tags: c#, nuget-package, csproj

I want to source some classes into another project. So, i have created a nuget package and want to use it in the project file(.csproj) file. So, that when i build my project it automatically uses the nuget package.

How do i provide the path for my local nuget package in the project file?

I have tried the below, but it didn't work?

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LocalNugetPackages\MyTestNuget-0.0.1.nupkg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: `Install-Package C:\Path\To\Some\File.nupkg` set full path

Comment: Like this?
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="Install-Package C:\Path\To\Some\File.nupkg" />
</ItemGroup>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400069/add-a-package-with-a-local-package-file-in-dotnet maybe useful

Comment: Is MyTestNuget.csproj part of your solution?

Comment: yes, it is @Hank

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use it as a nupkg? If you have a `ProjectReference` to a project, that link is automatically converted into a NuGet package dependency when you pack the dependent project.